# HTML Table Export jquery Plugin is not exporting more than 4 colums and rows PDF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, jquery-plugins

I am using HTML Table Export jquery Plugin for exporting html table to pdf but it is not exporting more than 4 Rows and Colums and also it is not adding border to table colums and row when i am exporting the html table to pdf.

Can anyone suggest me how can i do that..
Please Help me...
Here is my code for it

```
$('#datatable_example').tableExport({type:'pdf',pdfFontSize:'7',escape:'false'});
```

Comment: hi..Am facing same problem now can you help me!